# What causes "file changed on disk; really edit the buffer?" for files on a network share?

Tags: files

What causes "file changed on disk; really edit the buffer?" for files on a network share?

I edit files on an SMB share and I get constantly this question: "changed on disk; really edit the buffer? (y, n, r or C-h)"

I have auto-save, so if I hit "n", it just saves the file;)

It only happens when editing files on the network share.

What can be causing this? I don't share the files with anyone. It's an SMB server on a Windows system where I have some git repositories. I have exclusive access.

EDIT:
If I disable auto-save, I don't see this message popping up all the time.

It seems I can now make the message appear by writing something and then quickly save.

Keep in mind that this message only appears on SMB network filesystem, so I think there is some kind of network delay involved here.

Comment: "*What can be causing this?*" -- File is changed on disk...

Comment: Right, but it happens like every five minutes as I'm editing the files and no; nothing has changed, because if I say NO, then auto-saves just saves it. I believe this has something to do with timestamps on SMB filesystems, being somewhat delayed over the network.

Comment: So ... you didn't share files with other people (or programs) who have write-permission? If so, please say it in your question description.